# OPC-UA server in a remote access computer

Tags: server, remote-access, remote-server, opc-ua

I am trying to connect an OPC-UA server with an OPC-UA client. I am using a remote desktop connection. Is it the reason that I am not getting any server discovered by Matlab OPC UA or Aspen CIMIO even though they are running?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  This is not programming related.

Answer (score 0):

"Discovered" or just "connected"? Connecting to the remote OPC UA server is normal process so if you cannot connect I would check if there is connection can be made in the first place (firewall) and if certificate is used and what is policy.

Can you put the server on your local computer and check the connection then?